# Differences between following two functions

Tags: binary-tree

I am writing code to delete a node with val 1. I have implemented two functions for it. both apparently seems same to me, but gives a different result. please, can anybody point out why its happening like this?
code:-

The two functions are

- node deleteNodeWithVal1Funct1(node root)
- void deleteNodeWithVal1Funct2(node root)

public class Doubt1 {

```
class node  
{ 
    int data; 
    node left, right; 

    public node()
    {
        this.data = 0; 
        left=right=null;
    }
    public node(int data)  
    { 
        this.data = data; 
        left=right=null;
    } 
} ;

public static void printTreeInoreder(node root)
{
    if(root==null)
        return;
    
    printTreeInoreder(root.left);
    System.out.print(" "+root.data);
    printTreeInoreder(root.right);
    
}
public static node deleteNodeWithVal1Funct1(node root)
{
    if(root==null)
        return null;
    if(root.data==1)
        return null;
    root.left=deleteNodeWithVal1Funct1(root.left);
    root.right=deleteNodeWithVal1Funct1(root.right);
    return root;
}
public static void deleteNodeWithVal1Funct2(node root)
{
    if(root==null)
        return ;
    if(root.data==1)
    {   
        root=null;
        return;
    }
    deleteNodeWithVal1Funct2(root.left);
    deleteNodeWithVal1Funct2(root.right);
}
public static void main(String s[])
{
    Doubt1 ob=new Doubt1();
    node tree=ob.new node(0);  //        0
    tree.left=ob.new node(1);  // ->    / \
    tree.right=ob.new node(2); //      1   2
    printTreeInoreder(tree);  // gives 1 0 2
    deleteNodeWithVal1Funct2(tree);
    printTreeInoreder(tree);   //  gives  1 0 2  why ?why not 02 ?
    deleteNodeWithVal1Funct1(tree);
    printTreeInoreder(tree);  //   gives 0 2    why? whynot 1 0 2 ?
}
```

}

Comment: What does "both apparently seems same to me" mean? Obviously they are not the same.

Comment: Use a debugger and pen and paper. Step through your code and draw at each step, what the program is doing. That will make you understand what's happening.

Comment: please share your traversal code too

Comment: dear @matt , by  'both apparently seems  same to me ' I meant I  expected both to give same results.

Comment: dear @DushyantSingh i will share the entire program.